# Dynamically include javascript code from within javascript file

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I'm inserting the following script, which is on my own server, into an external page of a 3rd party: www.test.com/test.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var protocol = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
  var ttScript = document.createElement('script');ttScript.async = true;
  ttScript.src = '//www.example.com/script/mycode.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ttScript);
})();
</script>
```

This is the other script I want to dynamically inject, please note that it can't just be added to the above script! I want this script to be dynamically available.
This complete code, will later be stored within object `message.jsScript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tt_totalordervalue;
function tt_getordervalue(){
    tt_totalordervalue=$('#subtotal');
    console.log(tt_totalordervalue);
}
</script>
```

In file `mycode.js`:

I want to dynamically add the above script and call the function `tt_getordervalue` defined in there, I'm now trying to do this as below. Notice that I also want to assign the value of variable `tt_totalordervalue` which is defined in the dynamic script, to a variable in my `mycode.js`:

```
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(message.jsScript);
console.log('script added');
tt_getordervalue();
console.log('function called');
var val = tt_totalordervalue;
```

I however then get the error `Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.`

Why?

Comment: If you're set on doing this (not sure I understand WHY) and you really don't want to define the second script in a file to be dynamically added (like you did with the first one) I believe it is possible to create the script element and then set the `innerHTML` with the desired code to be run. Its still going to wind up in the global scope though.

Comment: @JaredSmith 
The reason is that I want to keep the implementation of this code consistent across any 3rd party site and that the 2nd dynamic script is site specific.
When I do it like this:
var ttScript = document.createElement('script'); ttScript.async = true;
ttScript.innerHTML(message.jsScript);

I get error `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function` on the line where I try to set the innerHTML...

And I want it to be in the global scope so that the variables I declare in that script are available everywhere (mainly in `mycode.js`)

Comment: innerHTML is an attribute, not a method: ttScript.innerHTML = message.jsScript

Comment: Ok, that was kinda stupid of me :)
I now get `Uncaught ReferenceError: tt_getordervalue is not defined`
I also don't see the script anywhere when I view page source or inspect the page (not sure if I should).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works on chrome on a Mac (sorry, was too lazy to cross test):

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = 'window.doStuff = function(){alert("do")}';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
doStuff();
```

Comment: That works...even without the `window.doStuff` line...does that add any value btw?

Comment: @Flo: `window.doStuff ...` declares a global variable called `doStuff` which is a function that alerts "do". It is intended as a sample code. Obviously you should replace it with your code instead.

Comment: I usually use the google closure compiler with advanced optimizations which more or less requires explicitly declaring globals as properties of the global object. Force of habit.